# Are bitmaps supposed to be 2-byte or 4-byte aligned?

Tags: c++, bitmap, msdn, bitmapfactory

MSDN documentation seems to contradict itself:

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says:

> For uncompressed RGB formats, the minimum stride is always the image width in bytes, rounded up to the nearest DWORD.

While [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183371.aspx) it says:

> The number of bytes in each scan line. This value must be divisible by 2, because the system assumes that the bit values of a bitmap form an array that is word aligned.

So sometimes MSDN wants a 4-byte aligned stride and sometimes it wants a 2-byte aligned stride. Which is right?

To be more specific, when saving a bitmap file should I use a 4-byte stride or a 2-byte stride?

Comment: From your first link `For YUV formats, there is no general rule for calculating the minimum stride` so presumably there is at least one YUV format that has a two byte stride alignment.

Comment: From your second link it is clear the page mainly describes *monochrome* bitmaps. It must be a pretty old page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first quote is accurate. The second dates back to the 16-bit version of Windows and did not get edited as it should have.  Not entirely unusual, GDI32 docs have had a fair amount of mistakes.

Do note that the up voted answer is not accurate.  Monochrome bitmaps still have a stride that's a multiple of 4, there is no special rule that makes it 2.  A bit of .NET code to demonstrate this:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
var bdata = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
Console.WriteLine(bdata.Stride);
```

Output: 4

Answer (score 0):

> **For uncompressed RGB formats**, the minimum stride is always the image width in bytes, rounded up to the nearest DWORD.

Bitmaps are not necessarily always uncompressed RGB, they might be monochrome. In the `BITMAP` structure, the member `bmBitsPixel` specifies the number of bits per pixel, so it is valid for it to be 1. So, you should save RGB bitmaps with a byte stride that is a multiple of 4, and save monochrome bitmap with a stride that is a multiple of 2.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateBitmap`/`CreateBitmapIndirect`/`BITMAP` struct - are all pre-Windows 3.0 APIs that was supposed to be used on 16-bit processors. Thats why they are using this 16-bit aligned stride.

All newer APIs are using 32bit stride aligment (`sizeof(DWORD)`).

You can use "newer" APIs (post-Windows 3.0) like `CreateDIBitmap` or `CreateCompatibleBitmap`/`SetDiBits` if your buffer have 32-bit aligned strides.

As for files - they are using `BITMAPINFO`/`BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure and [implies 32bit stride aligment](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader#calculating-surface-stride).